# Lasers : Threshold Pump Power for Laser Oscillation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

I was working my way through some basic laser problems , when I cam across this one :

> Consider the ruby laser for which we have the following values of the various parameters:
>
> $N =$ $1.6$ x $10^{19}$ $cm^{-3}$  ;  $t_{sp}$ = $3$ x $10^{-3}$ $s$ ;  $v_p$ = $6.25$ x $10^{14}$ $Hz$
>
> - Find the threshold pump power for laser oscillation , $P_t$ = $Nh\nu$ $/$ $2$$t_{sp}$
> - If we assume that the efficiency of the pumping source to be $25 $% and also that only $25$% of the pump light is absorbed on passage through the ruby rod, then the electrical threshold power comes out to be how much ?

I am able to solve the first part but am all thumbs in the second part - can someone help me out ?

<sup>**Disclaimer**: This is not a homework question . I am preparing for a physics exam and was solving these questions / examples from the book recommended by my instructor.</sup>

Comment: This is not really on-topic in this site; we are not a homework help site. Please read carefully [our homework and exercises guidelines](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/). What is it about this problem that confuses you?

Comment: Hi , @EmilioPisanty - it is not a homework problem , but a problem I encountered while studying for my exams ; the problem I have is that we have calculated $P_t$ in the first part , so for the second part - how de we factor in the information about efficiency and absorption given to find a new value for the threshold power ? would be grateful if you can explain it as an answer and not a comment :)

Comment: @pranav - although it is not 'homework' set by a teacher, we still consider this as 'homework and exercises' type problem. The best way to ask a question like this is to show how you did the first part and then how far you got with the second in your question... you can see examples of how to do this at http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6442/

Comment: As Tom mentioned, whether this was set as formal homework by an instructor or not is not that relevant. Do read the guidelines I linked to. We are happy to answer conceptual problems but you cannot dump a set piece and hope for the answer to magically appear. You need to do more than provide your workings for the first part; you need to identify the specific concept or procedure that's tripping you up and ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency of the pumping source is $x$ means that $x$ amount of electrical power is converted to energy which is useful for pumping the laser medium.  The absorption of the pump is $y$ means that $y$ amount of the energy from the pump source is actually pumped into the medium to generate the population inversion necessary for lasing.  The total amount of electrical power $P_E$ which makes it into the laser medium is therefore $x\ y\ P_E$.